# jbutton event ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Good day, I've a project which I'm implementing, and for this class which is NewPatient(), I've 3 buttons which I want to trigger events for, but unfortunately I'm so far able to trigger the events for two of my buttons which are BACK and CLEAR. but the SUBMIT one is not triggering any event which I don't understand. I don't know what i' missing. I've posted bellow m 3 classes

```
    in short that is how I refined it 

    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class MyCare 
    {   

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {

                NewPatient application = new NewPatient();

            application.setVisible(true);

            application.setLocation(500,150);
            //application.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

          }
    }

    /**
     * @(#)NewPatient.java
     *
     *
     * @author 
     * @version 1.00 2014/9/8
     */

        import javax.swing.JFrame;
        import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
        import javax.swing.JLabel;
        import javax.swing.JTextField;
        import javax.swing.JPanel;
        import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
        import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
        import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
        import javax.swing.border.Border;
        import java.awt.Color;
        import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
        import javax.swing.JButton;
        import javax.swing.Icon;
        import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
        import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
        import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
        import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
        import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
        import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
        import java.awt.Font;
        import javax.swing.JComboBox;
        import java.util.Random;
        import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
        import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
        import javax.swing.JTextArea;
        import javax.swing.Box;
        import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

        public class NewPatient extends JFrame implements ActionListener
        {
            //////////////////////// new patient labels

            private JLabel name;
            private JLabel sname;
            private JLabel initial;

            /////////////////////////////// new patient textfields

            private JTextField nameField;
            private JTextField snameField;
            private JTextField initialField;
        //          
            /////// buttons

            private JButton back;
            private JButton clear;
            private JButton send;

            ///// container

            private JPanel container;

            public NewPatient() 
            {
                super("NEW PATIENT");   

                this.setSize(600,580);
                this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
                this.setResizable(false);       


                //////////////// initializing and setting the main panel

                container = new JPanel();


                Border titleBorder = new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK),"REGISTER");
                container.setBorder(titleBorder);
                container.setLayout(null);

                //////////////////////// folder 


                name = new JLabel("NAME(S):");
                name.setBounds(10,85,80,15);
    //    name.setFont(labeNameFont);

                nameField = new JTextField();
                nameField.setBounds(80,80,150,27);
    //          nameField.setFont(labeNameFont);


                initialField = new JTextField(15);
                initialField.setBounds(407,80,60,27);
    //          initialField.setFont(labeNameFont);


                ///////////////// surname

                sname = new JLabel("SURNAME:");
                sname.setBounds(10,119,80,15);
    //          sname.setFont(labeNameFont);

                snameField = new JTextField(15);
                snameField.setBounds(80,115,150,27);
    //          snameField.setFont(labeNameFont);


                //////////////////////////////      back

                back = new JButton("BACK");
    //          back.setFont(labeNameFont);
                back.setBounds(80,490,80,27);

                ///////////////////////// clear

                clear = new JButton("CLEAR");
    //          clear.setFont(labeNameFont);
                clear.setBounds(280,490,80,27);

                ///////////////////////// Proceed

                send = new JButton("SUBMIT");
    //          send.setFont(labeNameFont);
                send.setBounds(480,490,80,27);

                ////////////////add components to panel

                registerPatient();

                ///////////////// register button events

                back.addActionListener(this);
                clear.addActionListener(this);
                send.addActionListener(this);
    ////            countryBox.addItemListener(this);

                ////////////adding panel


                add(container);

            }

                   public void registerPatient()
           {

                container.add(name);
                container.add(nameField);
                container.add(sname);
                container.add(snameField);



                ////////// add buttons

                container.add(back);
                container.add(clear);
                container.add(send);


                this.setVisible(true);
                this.setLocation(500,80);
           }


           /////////////////// clear fields

           public void clearFields()
           {

                nameField.setText("");

                snameField.setText("");


           }

           //////////////////////// triggering events



           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
           {
                if(event.getActionCommand().equals("BACK"))
                {
    //              

                    this.dispose();
                }


                if(event.getActionCommand().equals("CLEAR"))
                {
                    clearFields();
                }


                if(event.getActionCommand().equals("SUBMIT"))
                {
                    //ValidateInput validateData = new ValidateInput(); //// input validation

                    FullDetails mydetails = new FullDetails();

                    System.out.println("gtmtfsgsdg");

                    try
                    {
                        if(!ValidateInput.validateFirstName(nameField.getText()))
                        {
                            System.out.println("youtube");

                                            String message = String.format("Invalid Format!!! NAME must only be one word");  

                                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,message, "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }

                        else 
                        {
                            mydetails.setFirstName(nameField.getText()) ;

                            if(!ValidateInput.validateSurName(snameField.getText()))
                            {
                                String msg = String.format("Invalid Format!!! SURNAME must only be one word");  

                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg, "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            }

                            else{

                                mydetails.setSurname(snameField.getText());
                            }

                        }


                    }

                catch(Exception e)
                    {


                         String msg = String.format("Invalid input. Please make sure that you have filled every text fields!!! Please enter a correct one");  

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg, "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }

           }

        } 


    /**
         * @(#)ValidateInput.java
         */

        public class ValidateInput 
        {
            public static boolean validateFirstName(String firstName)
            {
                return firstName.matches("[a-zA-Z]*");
            }

            public static boolean validateSurName(String surname)
            {
                return surname.matches("[A-zA-z]+(['-][a-zA-Z]+)*");
            }
            public static boolean validateInitial(String initial)
            {
                return initial.matches("[A-Z]*");
            }
         }


    public class FullDetails 
        {


            private static String firstName;

            private static String surname;

             public void setFirstName(String firstName)
            {
                this.firstName = firstName;
            }

            public String getFirstName()
            {
                return firstName;
            }

            public void setSurname(String surname)
            {
                this.surname = surname;
            }
            public String getSurname()
            {
                return surname;
            }
            public static String getSurnam()
            {
                return surname;
            }

        }
```

Comment: You've posted a ton of code, most completely unrelated to your problem, and this risks swamping us with unnecessary code, possibly preventing us from seeing your problem and being able to help you. Please understand that we don't want to see your whole program, especially if it's larger than 60 lines long, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem, in other words, a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is WAY too much code for us to read. Would you please shorten it down to the relevant part of it?

Comment: So are you ever seeing the output from the following line in console? System.out.println("gtmtfsgsdg");

Comment: nope i'm not seeing that output, but when i'm willing to clear my fields or going back to another panel, I'm able to do it. the only concern is about the submit button which though registered doesn't not trigger the event. it my first time posting so i'm trying to shorten the code too

Comment: In the console of your IDE, you should see "gtmtfsgsdg" every time you click the Submit button.

Comment: I'm sorry to keep belaboring a point, but again, if your still stuck, create and post your [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your current code does not show any reason why your console is not showing gtmtfsgsdg. Please look at the 2nd bullet in my answer's "less critical issues" section for what I'm asking you to post. We need to be able to run your code and reproduce your problem, and so far we can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a FullDetails object in your SUBMIT portion of the actionPerformed method, assign it to the mydetails variable, and appear to add some data to it, including name information, but then you don't appear to do anything with this object and its data. You will need to do something with this object, perhaps display its contents somewhere on your GUI, for it to do anything.

Also please note that your FullDetails class suffers from inappropriate use of static fields. Most all those fields should be non-static instance fields. By your doing this, each FullDetails instance will share all the same data, which risks severe side effects, including collections of FullDetails objects, none of them unique. You will want to fix this.

Other less critical issues:

- Your GUI uses mainly null layouts and `setBounds`, something you want to avoid doing since use of null layout as this makes for very inflexible GUI's that while they might look good on one platform look terrible on most other platforms or screen resolutions and that are very difficult to update and maintain.
- If you still need help, then as per my comment to your original post, you'll want to create and post a [minimal example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I see that you've shortened your posted code some, but it still has non-core objects such as JDateChooser, it still refers to other classes of yours that we don't have, such as PatientPanel, and still is without a main method meaning we cannot compile, run, nor test it.

---

**Edit**
I've tried to make a compilable version of your code, but when I run it, the System.out.println from within the SUBMIT portion works:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

//!! import com.toedter.calendar.*; //!! we don't have this package

public class NewPatient extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ItemListener {
   // ////////////////////// new patient labels
   // !! enter code here //!! WTF??? this shouldn't be here, non commented
   private JLabel name;
   private JLabel sname;
   private JLabel initial;
   private JLabel gender;
   private JLabel address;
   private JLabel confirm;
   private JLabel phone;
   private JLabel email;
   private JLabel dob;
   private JLabel country;
   private JLabel city;
   private JLabel province;
   private JLabel balance;
   private JLabel userName;
   private JLabel password;
   private JLabel mail;
   private JLabel folderLabel;
   private JLabel idLabel;
   private JLabel label;
   private JLabel label1;
   // ///////////////////////////// new patient textfields
   private JTextField nameField;
   private JTextField snameField;
   private JTextField initialField;
   // private JTextField dobField;
   private JTextField provinceField;
   private JTextField phoneField;
   private JTextField emailField;
   private JTextField balanceField;
   private JTextField userNameField;
   private JTextField folderField;
   private JTextField idField;
   private JTextField cityField;
   private JTextField mailField;
   // /////////////////// state province combo box
   private JComboBox countryBox;
   // private JComboBox cityBox;
   // private JComboBox provinceBox;
   // ////////////// password fields
   private JPasswordField passwordField;
   private JPasswordField confirmField;
   // /////////////// radio buttons
   private JRadioButton maleBtn;
   private JRadioButton femaleBtn;
   // ///////////// radio button group
   private ButtonGroup groupSex;
   // //////////////panel to containt components
   private JPanel container;
   // ///////////// fonts
   Font labeNameFont = null;
   // //////////// text area
   private JTextArea addressArea;
   // ///////////// box
   private Box boxArea;
   // /////////////////////// variables
   private static final String[] countryNames = { "", "BOTSWANA", "CONGO",
         "DR CONGO", "SOUTH AFRICA", "RWANDA", "ZIMBABWE" };
   // //////////////////// buttons
   private JButton back;
   private JButton clear;
   private JButton send;

   // ///////////// calendar
   // !! private JDateChooser chooser;
   public NewPatient() {
      super("NEW PATIENT");
      this.setSize(600, 580);
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      this.setResizable(false);
      // /////////////////// labels fonts
      labeNameFont = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 12);
      // ////////////// initializing and setting the main panel
      container = new JPanel();
      Border titleBorder = new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK),
            "REGISTER");
      container.setBorder(titleBorder);
      container.setLayout(null);
      // ////////////////////// folder
      folderLabel = new JLabel("FOLDER NUMBER:");
      folderLabel.setBounds(140, 30, 110, 25);
      folderLabel.setFont(labeNameFont);
      folderField = new JTextField(15);
      folderField.setBounds(250, 30, 90, 27);
      folderField.setEditable(false);
      folderField.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
      folderField.setText(patientNum());
      folderField.setFont(labeNameFont);
      // ////////////////// name
      name = new JLabel("NAME(S):");
      name.setBounds(10, 85, 80, 15);
      name.setFont(labeNameFont);
      nameField = new JTextField();
      nameField.setBounds(80, 80, 150, 27);
      nameField.setFont(labeNameFont);
      // //////////////////// initial
      initial = new JLabel("INITIAL:");
      initial.setFont(labeNameFont);
      initial.setBounds(347, 82, 80, 20);
      initialField = new JTextField(15);
      initialField.setBounds(407, 80, 60, 27);
      initialField.setFont(labeNameFont);
      // /////////////// surname
      sname = new JLabel("SURNAME:");
      sname.setBounds(10, 119, 80, 15);
      sname.setFont(labeNameFont);
      snameField = new JTextField(15);
      snameField.setBounds(80, 115, 150, 27);
      snameField.setFont(labeNameFont);
      // //////////////////////////// gender radio and group button
      gender = new JLabel("GENDER:");
      gender.setBounds(347, 117, 80, 15);
      gender.setFont(labeNameFont);
      maleBtn = new JRadioButton("MALE");
      maleBtn.setBounds(407, 114, 80, 20);
      maleBtn.setFont(labeNameFont);
      femaleBtn = new JRadioButton("FEMALE");
      femaleBtn.setFont(labeNameFont);
      femaleBtn.setBounds(490, 114, 80, 20);
      groupSex = new ButtonGroup();
      groupSex.add(maleBtn);
      groupSex.add(femaleBtn);
      // ////////////////// id
      idLabel = new JLabel("ID NUM:");
      idLabel.setBounds(10, 154, 80, 15);
      idLabel.setFont(labeNameFont);
      idField = new JTextField(15);
      idField.setBounds(80, 150, 150, 27);
      idField.setFont(labeNameFont);
      // /////////////////// address
      address = new JLabel("Address:");
      address.setBounds(347, 154, 70, 15);
      address.setFont(labeNameFont);
      boxArea = Box.createHorizontalBox();
      addressArea = new JTextArea(10, 10);
      addressArea.setLineWrap(true);
      addressArea.setFont(labeNameFont);
      boxArea.setBounds(407, 150, 150, 80);
      boxArea.setFont(labeNameFont);
      boxArea.add(new JScrollPane(addressArea));
      // /////////// date of birth
      dob = new JLabel("D.O.B:");
      dob.setBounds(10, 190, 50, 15);
      dob.setFont(labeNameFont);
      /*
       * dobField = new JTextField(15); dobField.setBounds(80,185,150,27);
       * dobField.setFont(labeNameFont);
       */
      // !! chooser = new JDateChooser();
      // chooser.setFont(labeNameFont);
      // chooser.setBounds(80,185,150,27);
      // ///////////////////////// country
      country = new JLabel("COUNTRY:");
      country.setBounds(10, 230, 70, 15);
      country.setFont(labeNameFont);
      countryBox = new JComboBox(countryNames);
      countryBox.setBounds(80, 225, 150, 27);
      countryBox.setFont(labeNameFont);
      countryBox.setMaximumRowCount(3);
      // /////////////////////////////////// city
      city = new JLabel("CITY:");
      city.setFont(labeNameFont);
      city.setBounds(347, 248, 70, 15);
      // city.setVisible(false);
      cityField = new JTextField(15);
      cityField.setFont(labeNameFont);
      cityField.setBounds(407, 242, 150, 27);
      // cityField.setVisible(false);
      cityField.setEditable(false);
      // //////////////////// province
      province = new JLabel("PROVINCE:");
      province.setBounds(10, 271, 80, 15);
      province.setFont(labeNameFont);
      provinceField = new JTextField(15);
      provinceField.setFont(labeNameFont);
      provinceField.setBounds(80, 267, 150, 27);
      provinceField.setEditable(false);
      // /////////////////////// phone
      phone = new JLabel("PHONE:");
      phone.setBounds(10, 313, 70, 15);
      phone.setFont(labeNameFont);
      phoneField = new JTextField(15);
      phoneField.setBounds(80, 306, 150, 27);
      phoneField.setFont(labeNameFont);
      // /////////////////////// email
      email = new JLabel("EMAIL:");
      email.setBounds(347, 288, 70, 15);
      email.setFont(labeNameFont);
      emailField = new JTextField(15);
      emailField.setBounds(409, 282, 150, 27);
      emailField.setFont(labeNameFont);
      mail = new JLabel("CONFIRM EMAIL:");
      mail.setBounds(347, 335, 100, 15);
      mail.setFont(labeNameFont);
      mailField = new JTextField(15);
      mailField.setBounds(410, 360, 150, 27);
      mailField.setFont(labeNameFont);
      label1 = new JLabel("\" name@kalilinux.org \"");
      label1.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 12));
      label1.setBounds(420, 300, 150, 27);
      // ///////////// phone formaat label
      // Font font = null;
      label = new JLabel("(0XX-XXX-XXXX)");
      label.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 12));
      label.setBounds(100, 325, 150, 27);
      // ////////////// address
      balance = new JLabel("BALANCE:");
      balance.setBounds(10, 360, 70, 15);
      balance.setFont(labeNameFont);
      balanceField = new JTextField(15);
      balanceField.setBounds(80, 357, 150, 27);
      balanceField.setFont(labeNameFont);
      // /////// username and password
      userName = new JLabel("USER NAME:");
      userName.setBounds(10, 395, 100, 15);
      userName.setFont(labeNameFont);
      userNameField = new JTextField(15);
      userNameField.setBounds(80, 392, 150, 27);
      userNameField.setFont(labeNameFont);
      password = new JLabel("PASSWORD:");
      password.setBounds(10, 435, 80, 15);
      password.setFont(labeNameFont);
      passwordField = new JPasswordField(15);
      passwordField.setBounds(80, 432, 150, 27);
      passwordField.setFont(labeNameFont);
      confirm = new JLabel("CONFIRM PASSWORD:");
      confirm.setBounds(347, 403, 150, 15);
      confirm.setFont(labeNameFont);
      confirmField = new JPasswordField(15);
      confirmField.setBounds(410, 425, 150, 27);
      confirmField.setFont(labeNameFont);
      // //////////////////////////// back
      back = new JButton("BACK");
      back.setFont(labeNameFont);
      back.setBounds(80, 490, 80, 27);
      // /////////////////////// clear
      clear = new JButton("CLEAR");
      clear.setFont(labeNameFont);
      clear.setBounds(280, 490, 80, 27);
      // /////////////////////// Proceed
      send = new JButton("SUBMIT");
      send.setFont(labeNameFont);
      send.setBounds(480, 490, 80, 27);
      // //////////////add components to panel
      registerPatient();
      // /////////////// register button events
      back.addActionListener(this);
      clear.addActionListener(this);
      send.addActionListener(this);
      countryBox.addItemListener(this);
      // //////////adding panel
      add(container);
   }

   public String patientNum() {
      Random numberGenerated = new Random();
      String myNumGen = " MKW - ";
      int starter;
      starter = 473 + numberGenerated.nextInt(9528);
      String start = String.format("%d", starter);
      return myNumGen + " " + start;
   }

   public void registerPatient() {
      container.add(folderLabel);
      container.add(folderField);
      container.add(name);
      container.add(nameField);
      container.add(sname);
      container.add(snameField);
      container.add(idLabel);
      container.add(idField);
      container.add(dob);
      // container.add(dobField);
      // !! container.add(chooser);
      container.add(initial);
      container.add(initialField);
      container.add(gender);
      container.add(maleBtn);
      container.add(femaleBtn);
      container.add(address);
      container.add(boxArea);
      container.add(country);
      container.add(countryBox);
      container.add(city);
      container.add(cityField);
      container.add(province);
      container.add(provinceField);
      container.add(phone);
      container.add(phoneField);
      container.add(label);
      container.add(label1);
      container.add(email);
      container.add(emailField);
      container.add(balance);
      container.add(balanceField);
      container.add(mail);
      container.add(mailField);
      container.add(userName);
      container.add(userNameField);
      container.add(password);
      container.add(passwordField);
      container.add(confirm);
      container.add(confirmField);
      // //////// add buttons
      container.add(back);
      container.add(clear);
      container.add(send);
      this.setVisible(true);
      this.setLocation(500, 80);
   }

   // ///////////////// clear fields
   public void clearFields() {
      folderField.setText(patientNum());
      folderField.setFont(labeNameFont);
      nameField.setText("");
      initialField.setText("");
      snameField.setText("");
      idField.setText("");
      // !! chooser.setCalendar(null);
      provinceField.setText("");
      cityField.setText("");
      emailField.setText("");
      confirmField.setText("");
      passwordField.setText("");
      mailField.setText("");
      userNameField.setText("");
      balanceField.setText("");
      addressArea.setText("");
      phoneField.setText("");
      countryBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
      groupSex.clearSelection();
      // femaleBtn.setSelected(false);
   }

   // ////////////////////// triggering events
   public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent myevent) {
      Object selected = countryBox.getSelectedItem();
      if (selected.toString().equals("")) {
         provinceField.setText("");
         cityField.setText("");
      } else if (selected.toString().equals("BOTSWANA")) {
         provinceField.setText("SOUTH-EAST");
         cityField.setText("GABORONE");
      } else if (selected.toString().equals("CONGO")) {
         provinceField.setText("POOL");
         cityField.setText("BRAZAVILLE");
      } else if (selected.toString().equals("DR CONGO")) {
         provinceField.setText("KINSHASA");
         cityField.setText("KINSHASA");
      } else if (selected.toString().equals("SOUTH AFRICA")) {
         provinceField.setText("WESTERN CAPE");
         cityField.setText("CAPE TOWN");
      } else if (selected.toString().equals("RWANDA")) {
         provinceField.setText("KIGALI");
         cityField.setText("KIGALI CITY");
      } else if (selected.toString().equals("ZIMBABWE")) {
         provinceField.setText("HARARE");
         cityField.setText("HARARE");
      }
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
      if (event.getActionCommand().equals("BACK")) {
         PatientPanel patient = new PatientPanel();
         patient.setVisible(true);
         patient.setLocation(500, 250);
         dispose();
      }
      if (event.getActionCommand().equals("CLEAR")) {
         clearFields();
      }
      if (event.getActionCommand().equals("SUBMIT")) {
         // ValidateInput validateData = new ValidateInput(); //// input
         // validation
         FullDetails mydetails = new FullDetails();
         System.out.println("gtmtfsgsdg");
         try {
            if (!ValidateInput.validateFirstName(nameField.getText())) {
               System.out.println("youtube");
               String message = String
                     .format("Invalid Format!!! NAME must only be one word");
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, "ERROR",
                     JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            } else {
               mydetails.setFirstName(nameField.getText());
               if (!ValidateInput.validateSurName(snameField.getText())) {
                  String msg = String
                        .format("Invalid Format!!! SURNAME must only be one word");
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg, "ERROR",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
               } else {
                  mydetails.setSurname(snameField.getText());
               }
            }
         } catch (Exception e) {
            String msg = String
                  .format("Invalid input. Please make sure that you have filled every text fields!!! Please enter a correct one");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg, "ERROR",
                  JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
         }
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      NewPatient gui = new NewPatient();
      gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      gui.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class ValidateInput {
   public static boolean validateFirstName(String firstName) {
      return firstName.matches("[a-zA-Z]*");
   }

   public static boolean validateSurName(String surname) {
      return surname.matches("[A-zA-z]+(['-][a-zA-Z]+)*");
   }

   public static boolean validateInitial(String initial) {
      return initial.matches("[A-Z]*");
   }
}

class FullDetails {
   // !! These fields should not be static
   private static String firstName;
   private static String surname;

   public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
   }

   public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
   }

   public void setSurname(String surname) {
      this.surname = surname;
   }

   public String getSurname() {
      return surname;
   }

   public static String getSurnam() {
      return surname;
   }
}

//!! a bare bones class to allow your code to compile
class PatientPanel extends JPanel {
   public PatientPanel() {
      add(new JLabel("Patient Panel"));
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Patient Panel"));
   }
}
```

This code has not been "fixed" in any way and still has the issues that I've mentioned above.

---

**Edit**
A small example program showing some of the things that I've discussed.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
// I try to gear my GUI's towards creation of JPanels, not JFrames
// I then can put the panel into a JFrame or into something else if desired
public class SimpleGui extends JPanel {
   private JTextField firstNameField = new JTextField(10);
   private JTextField lastNameField = new JTextField(10);
   private JTextComponent[] textComponents = {firstNameField, lastNameField};
   private DefaultListModel<SimpleDetails> detailsListModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
   private JList<SimpleDetails> detailsList = new JList<>(detailsListModel);

   public SimpleGui() {
      JPanel dataEntryPanel = new JPanel();
      dataEntryPanel.add(new JLabel("First Name:"));
      dataEntryPanel.add(firstNameField);
      dataEntryPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15)); // add space
      dataEntryPanel.add(new JLabel("Last Name:"));
      dataEntryPanel.add(lastNameField);

      JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 5, 0));
      buttonPanel.add(new JButton(new ClearAction("Clear", KeyEvent.VK_C)));
      buttonPanel.add(new JButton(new SubmitAction("Submit", KeyEvent.VK_S)));
      buttonPanel.add(new JButton(new ExitAction("Exit", KeyEvent.VK_X)));

      JPanel detailsPanel = new JPanel();
      detailsList.setPrototypeCellValue(new SimpleDetails("AAAAAAAAAAAA", "BBBBBBBBBBBB"));
      detailsList.setVisibleRowCount(12);
      JScrollPane detailsScrollPane = new JScrollPane(detailsList);
      detailsScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
      detailsPanel.add(detailsScrollPane);

      setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
      add(detailsPanel);
      add(dataEntryPanel);
      add(buttonPanel);
   }

   public void clearTextFields() {
      for (JTextComponent jTextComponent : textComponents) {
         jTextComponent.setText("");
      }
   }

   private class SubmitAction extends AbstractAction {
      public SubmitAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
         super(name);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         String firstName = firstNameField.getText();
         String lastName = lastNameField.getText();

         // validate input here or after creating details object
         // if valid, then 

         // create your details object
         SimpleDetails simpleDetails = new SimpleDetails(firstName, lastName);

         if (Validate.test(simpleDetails)) {
            // and then DO something with it. 
            // Here I add it to a JList
            detailsListModel.addElement(simpleDetails);
         } else {
            // notify user that data is bad
            // consider clearing the GUI
            clearTextFields();
         }

      }
   }

   private class ClearAction extends AbstractAction {

      public ClearAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
         super(name);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         clearTextFields();
      }
   }

   private class ExitAction extends AbstractAction {
      public ExitAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
         super(name);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         // clean up an problems
         Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(SimpleGui.this);
         win.dispose();
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      SimpleGui mainPanel = new SimpleGui();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleGui");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // so that the program runs on the Swing event thread
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class SimpleDetails {
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;

   public SimpleDetails(String firstName, String lastName) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.lastName = lastName;
   }

   public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
   }

   public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
   }

   public String getLastName() {
      return lastName;
   }

   public void setLastName(String lastName) {
      this.lastName = lastName;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return lastName + ", " + firstName;
   }

}

class Validate {
   public static boolean test(SimpleDetails simpleDetails) {
      if (simpleDetails.getFirstName().trim().isEmpty()) {
         return false;
      }
      if (simpleDetails.getLastName().trim().isEmpty()) {
         return false;
      }

      // default, has passed all tests
      return true;
   }
}
```